# Testing private methods, clarification needed

Tags: testing

In my `src`, there exist a class which contains a method

```
public static boolean doExtensionsMatch(String s, String t) {
```

There is nothing wrong with it, except that there is no need for it to be public. It is used inside the class where it is declared.

It is `public` however, since some time ago, i felt this method needed to be tested directly and thus, `private` visibility did not work for me.

At this point:

- I'd rather not throw away those tests. If i make the method `private` however, tests will become unusable.
- I would rather for tests to remain in it's current `src-test` folder, thus maintaining separate locations for source and tests

So, you tell me, what should i do?

Should i change the method to private and delete the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test **interface** to prove that class behaves as it should.

So private methods don't need to be tested as long as they aren't accessible. And even more - you shouldn't care of how interface does its work, you should be fine with just the results.

You test the behaviour, not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using partial classes.  If your test classes are partial classes of the class to be tested they will have access to all methods and variables whether or not they are public.

Comment: What do you mean by partial classes?

Comment: @JAM: he means http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx though I don't agree it is a good idea to do

Comment: Check out this page I think it will help clarify: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2006/04/14/442836.aspx)

Comment: I think it is ok as long as you keep the tests in separate assemblies and don't compile them in to release versions.